# passing pointer as size of an array in C

Tags: c

I want to pass a pointer as a size element of an array

example:

```
void hello(int array1[how can i refer pointer "ptr" here][2])
    {
   // i want to access the array used in the main() here
    printf("hi");
    }

int main()
{
        int c=5;
        int *ptr=&c;

        a[*ptr][2];
       a[0][1]=0;
       a[0][2]=4;

 }
```

I apologize for not being clear with my question here , i want to access the array used in the main() function in my hello() function.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The answer has been pointed out by many people so far, but I have to echo the above question - why would you do that, it makes no sense! I assume your are working on a 32 bit system, so an int is only 32 bits, 4 bytes, and not a problem to copy if you are using it as an argument to a function, e.g

`void someFunc(int sizeofArray)`

Comment: Also, if you ask about C, don't tag your question C and C++. I removed the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the value pointed to by the pointer:

```
a[*ptr][2];
```

`ptr` is the address pointed to by the pointer not the value stored there. You use the dereference operator `*` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dereference operator `*`:

```
a[*ptr][2];
```

The expression `*ptr`  tells the compiler to use the value pointed to by `ptr`.

---

As for your updated question, that's not possible. But it's not needed either, as it's passed as a pointer anyway.

When declaring a function, this:

```
void foo(int a[5][5])
```

is the same as this:

```
void foo(int a[][2])
```

And also the same as this:

```
void foo(int (*a)[2])
```

Comment: I have edited my question a bit , Can some one answer that please

Answer (score 1):

Of course, `ptr` is not of type `int`, it's of type `int *` (integer pointer). An array subscript must be of type `int`.

Maybe what you want is `a[*ptr][2]`.

Comment: The array subscript must be an integer type, but it doesn't have to be `int` (it could be `size_t`, `unsigned`, `short`, `long long` etc).

Answer (score 1):

You need to deference the pointer by using *ptr so

```
int c = 5;
int *ptr = &c;

a[*ptr][2];
```

otherwise you are not using the value of ptr you are using its address in memory which returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

It has pretty much been answered already, you can't call an adress in the array `a[0x3950f2][2]`
Always use the pointer* to get the position in the array `a[*ptr][2]` to get the expected value - in this case: `a[*ptr][2]` == `a[5][2]`. You may read [this.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

**Edit to your updated question:** You can't to this. You *can* use the pointer when you call the function or when using the variable in the function.

**Your second edit:**

```
void hello(int **array1)
{
   // i want to access the array used in the main() here
    printf ("hi");
    a[0][0] = 24;
}

int main()
{
    int c = 5;
    int *ptr = &c;
    int **a;
    a[*ptr][2];
    a[0][1] = 0;
    a[0][2] = 4;

    hello (a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There you go. Hope that's what you expected.